# How to capture url requests made by my router?

Tags: xampp, router, wireshark, dyndns, noip

I'm trying to deploy my own Dynamic DNS service at Dreamhost and following some guides managed to get the server side functioning perfectly - when I open a url the DNS A record for a subdomain gets updated.

But when I place the data on the router and try to make it work (following the standards at dyndns or no-ip) the router fails to update.

Here's what I have:
 1. Server side works as I expected.
 2. Router works when using the default services (tested with no-ip) to update IP.
 3. If I fail the authentication on my server, then router throws an auth failed error - it's accessing the server and authenticating.
 4. Tried logging to see if at any point the script is even accessed, and it's not.

So I think the router is requesting a url that is different than I expect. I tried with /, white /update/ and with /nic/update/

At this point I wanted to see what the router is actually requesting. Fired up XAMPP, installed Wireshark, and tried to set the router to update my own computer. Found the requests and found a 301 response since the router is asking for /nic/update? and I have it on /nic/update/?.

Browser handles this redirect transparently but the router seems to not be requesting the new url. Might need to mess with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, the router was taking the redirect as a bad reply.
After messing around with mod_rewrite I got it to work.

Used this:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.cgi [L]
```